# Carregar informações do banco de dados em um textbox utilizando o modelo de camadas com C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Bom dia pessoal!
Sou inscrito novo no fórum, porém já os acompanho há tem algum tempo, estou finalizando um TCC da faculdade em C# (Visual Studio 2017), e estou com uma dificuldade no projeto que estou montando, onde o problema é o seguinte:
Meu projeto está em 4 camadas (DAL, BLL, Model e User Interface);
No banco de dados, tenho uma tabela chamada "endereco", que contém os campos cep, logradouro, bairro, cidade e uf;
Na tela de "Cadastro de Clientes", preciso que ao digitar o CEP em um campo MaskedTextBox, utilizando a propriedade "Leave" o mesmo faça uma consulta no banco de dados na tabela endereço, e se houver um registro o mesmo retorne os dados e preencha os devidos TextBox (logradouro, bairro, cidade e uf);
Caso não tenha no banco de dados, o mesmo fará uma consulta no Web Service (ISSO JÁ ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO).

Segue imagens do que já tenho.
[image: EnderecosBLL]
[image: EnderecosDAL]
[image: Formulário de Clientes]

Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido.
Obrigado!

Comment: Seja bem vinda Chris, evite imagens, entretanto no seu caso é aconselhado para ilustrar o problema. Outrossim, mantenha as imagens, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/402908/edit) sua pergunta e coloque os códigos para facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris_Rodrigues, sua consulta "ConsultaCep" está dando erro, pois é VOID e tem um return...

Troque de VOID para DataTable, assim:

```
public DataTable ConsultaCep(string cep)
{
   DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
   NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(...

   da.Fill(tabela);
   return tabelas;
}
```

Depois você recupera o valor do CEP dentro da DataTable do ConsultaCep, como você faz no listagem, mas verifique ANTES se o CEP foi retornado, se não veio, você vai precisar que o usuário preencha o CEP).
   Como vai retornar somente 1 registro, será algo assim:

```
   strCEP = dt.rows[0]["CEP"].ToString()
```

Veja também:

[Pegar valores das colunas de um DataTable](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/pegar-valores-das-colunas-de-um-datatable/420986)

[C# - Trabalhando com o objeto DataTable](http://www.macoratti.net/15/08/c_dtbl1.htm)

[Pegar valor do datatable e converter!](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/779ba7fb-1578-4dc1-b782-9cd61d847125/pegar-valor-do-datatable-e-converter?forum=aspnetpt)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Fabioln, deu certo o que eu queria fazer.

Comment: Valew Christian. Obrigado por me pontuar!